# Local image save on word document openXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, openxml, openxml-sdk

I read some docs realated to how construct the document, so i am building my app with building blocks, where each block is a component(title,image...).

So when i build my doc structure i have something like this:

```
DocRun accessTypeTitle  = new DocRun();
Run permissionTitle = accessTypeTitle.createParagraph("DOCUMENT ACCESS", "0475B9","16");

// document permission (ex: public, internal use only), defined on template side
DocRun accessTypePermission = new DocRun();
Run permission = accessTypePermission.createParagraph(document.documentAccess, "262626", "16");

DocRun disclaimerTitle = new DocRun();
Run disclaimerTitleTxt = disclaimerTitle.createParagraph("DISCLAIMER", "0475B9", "16");

DocRun disclaimerDescription = new DocRun();
Run disclaimerDescriptionTxt = disclaimerDescription.createParagraph(disclaimerTxt, "262626", "16");

var stream = new MemoryStream();
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);

    Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

    /*body.Append(new Paragraph(
             new Run(image)));*/

    body.Append(new Paragraph(
               new Run(permissionTitle)));

    body.Append(new Paragraph(
              new Run(permission)));

    body.Append(new Paragraph(
             new Run(disclaimerTitleTxt)));

    body.Append(new Paragraph(
             new Run(disclaimerDescriptionTxt)));

    mainPart.Document.Save();
}
```

I have an external dll that handles the functions, I need to have the same for my image.

Basically, the image should be the first thing added in the doc, I saw some docs where they access an uri and save the image on the path. I just need to access my images folder get the image and add it to the document.

**At the moment i have this:**

```
DocImage docImage = new DocImage();
Drawing image = docImage.addImage("2", "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/465786286825955328/JIN8xseJ_400x400.png");

namespace openXml
{
    public class DocImage
    {

        public Drawing addImage(String relationshipId,String uri)
        {
            // Define the reference of the image.
            var element =
                 new Drawing(
                     new DW.Inline(
                         new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                         new DW.EffectExtent()
                         {
                             LeftEdge = 0L,
                             TopEdge = 0L,
                             RightEdge = 0L,
                             BottomEdge = 0L
                         },
                         new DW.DocProperties()
                         {
                             Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                             Name = "Picture 1"
                         },
                         new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                             new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                         new A.Graphic(
                             new A.GraphicData(
                                 new PIC.Picture(
                                     new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                         new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                         {
                                             Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                             Name = "CriticalLogo"
                                         },
                                         new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                     new PIC.BlipFill(
                                         new A.Blip(
                                             new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                                 new A.BlipExtension()
                                                 {
                                                     Uri =
                                                       "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                                 })
                                         )
                                         {
                                             Embed = relationshipId,
                                             CompressionState =
                                             A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                         },
                                         new A.Stretch(
                                             new A.FillRectangle())),
                                     new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                         new A.Transform2D(
                                             new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                             new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                         new A.PresetGeometry(
                                             new A.AdjustValueList()
                                         )
                                         { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                             )
                             { Uri = uri })
                     )
                     {
                         DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                         DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U
                     });

            return element;
        } 
    }
}


var stream = new MemoryStream();
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);

    Body body = mainPart.Document.Body;

    body.Append(new Paragraph(
             new Run(image)));
}
```

the document gets created but is corrupted :/

Comment: Use OpenXML Productivity Tool to see the difference between between the generated word doc and the desired word doc. This will give you an idea as to what is missing. A document can be corrupt for various reasons.

Comment: ok, but for example how can i get the graphic data of my image, since in the tool it generates the image in a different section, i have no access to that in c#